# C# - Where are the immutable collections?

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

I'm reading a book and it introduces me to immutable collections which includes ImmutableDictionary, ImmutableHashSet and more.

The book says that its in Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable NuGet package but I can't find it. Any help? Also, I'm using .NET 4.6.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Go to http://nuget.org, then search for "concurrent collections"...

Comment: Those are the Immutable, not the concurrent collections. Concurrent collections are classes like ConcurrentQueue, ConcurrentStack, ConcurrentBag, BlockingCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They live under `System.Collections.Immutable`.

Try this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable